# Minecraft Candestroy data tag not working for mods

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, mods

I am attempting to make a block that destroys a MOD BLOCK, not a vanilla block.

I've tried:

`/give @p stone_pickaxe {CanDestroy:["popcornMod:popcornBlock"]}`

and alot of different caps of that.

Mod link: https://www.planetminecraft.com/mod/popcorn-mod/

Comment: Hi LAKottke, what have you tried so far?

Comment: A link to the mod would help.

Answer (score -2):

I looked in the json files and did a /give command using

```
/give stone_pickaxe 1 0 {CanDestroy:["popcorn_mod:popcornblock"]}
```

It also answered my other question "[Getting Mod ID's](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/360383/getting-mod-ids)"

Comment: Can you give the command that you used to create the pickaxe? A command to give a block doesn't answer the question.