# How do I get modded item/block IDs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

Is there any way to get the name ID for mod items? I have no idea how to do it at the moment, and I have tried the name with all the capital letter and underscore combinations I could try, can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked in the json files and did

```
/give popcorn_mod:popcornblock
```

and it worked! It also answered my other question of [How to make an item that destroys mod blocks](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/360380/minecraft-candestroy-data-tag-not-working-for-mods)

Answer (score 3):

You can press F3 + H which will enable tooltips. You can now hover over an item or block to see its id.

Comment: This did not work at all because it either did nothing or set my volume up.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? these combinations don't work on every system by default, more on how to resolve that on the wiki: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Controls

Comment: For any as blind as I, the numbers are listed right next to the normal item names listed in-game in brackets.